# wpdb->get_row() / get_results - is it possible to return an object instances of my own class?

Tags: wpdb

Is it possible to make wpdb->get_row return an object of a my own custom class instead of stdClass?

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't look like it's possible, at least there doesn't seem to be an elegant way. [`get_row()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L1452) invokes [`query()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L1176), which uses [`mysql_fetch_object()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php) with a single parameter, ie it's not possible to pass anything to its `class_name` parameter.

So, the only option left would be to extend the `wpdb` class, implement custom code so that it can return custom classes, and then create an instance of the new class in the global `$wpdb` variable before WordPress calls [`require_wp_db()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1//wp-includes/load.php#L316). But that would be some really ugly hack if you ask me.

Ofcourse you could always create instances of your custom classes manually and populate them from the retreived `stdClass` instance, just like WordPress does:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/post.php#L605

```
public function __construct( $post ) {
    foreach ( get_object_vars( $post ) as $key => $value )
        $this->$key = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is poorly documented but you can replace the database class by adding a "Drop-In" named `db.php` in the content directory. You could certainly make it return any object you want that way, but it would still need to be compatible with what WordPress expects, or things would break.

### Reference

http://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/05/01/must-use-and-drop-ins-plugins/

And here is a plugin that includes such a file:
http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wordpress-database-abstraction/trunk/wp-db-abstraction/db.php